# Broadcast receiver in Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, kotlin, unity-game-engine, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement a broadcast receiver system in Unity using the aar plugin to work in android apps.

At first I tried to implement all the logic in the plugin using kotlin coroutines, but I ran into an issue:

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:Lkotlinx/coroutines/CoroutineScope;

I added the `kotlin corutins` library to the Plugins/Android folder, but it didn't help.

Then I wrote a simple aar plugin in java that sends a broadcast and receives it if there is an app installed on the phone (this app also has a broadcast receiver), but my Unity app cannot fire the OnReseive method.
Maybe I'm missing some features.
Question: Is it possible to implement a Broadcast receiver system in Unity using the aar plugin, if so, how to do it?